# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, nullreferenceexception

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[day].ToString() != null)
{
    var test = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[day].ToString();
}
```

I have written these lines but when Form[day] doesn't contain any value, it gives an null object exception. How can I solve this ?

Comment: You can try maybe this, if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[day] != null)
{
    var test = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[day].ToString();
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check this value before access it. For example, like this:

```
var form = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;
if (form != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(day) && form.AllKeys.Contains(day))
{
    var test = form[day].ToString();
}
```